# Apache/PHP is determined to serve the wrong file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a page that is called with a url like
`http://testserver/path/to/foo/bar/`
but apache is serving the wrong file altogether.

`/path/to/` is a real directory where all the code and `.htaccess` file is. `foo/bar/` is supposed to redirect to `foo_bar.php` with a `RewriteRule`, but it never gets there. It's not a `mod_rewrite` issue as I have commented out all the rules that could be interfering, which should give me 404s for that request, but the same problem occurs:

the file that is served is `/path/to/foo.php`, so in it I `var_dump` `$_SERVER` and get:
`REQUEST_URI = /path/to/foo/bar/`
`SCRIPT_NAME = /path/to/foo.php`
`SCRIPT_FILENAME = /real/path/to/foo.php`
`PATH_INFO = /bar/`
`PATH_TRANSLATED = /real/bar/`
`PHP_SELF = /path/to/foo.php/bar/`

Why is this request being routed to this file at all?

Comment: What about posting your .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have [`mod_negotiation`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod%5Fnegotiation.html) installed? If so, that'll take your request and try to work out what file you really meant.  Unfortunately `mod_negotiation` gets confused by the reroute-magic from `mod_rewrite`, so make sure you disable `mod_negotiation`'s MultiViews option when you try to rewrite the request.

If your overwrite settings allow it, you can disable MultiViews with: `Options -MultiViews` in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: thanks. what an awful module to have on by default. i can't believe it does its thing before mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

mod_speling could be the culprit.  If it is enabled on your server. Try to disable it.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_speling.html

Answer (score 0):

It's one of the modules mentioned in @murze's and @Jacco's answers in combination with the `PATH_INFO` mechanism that is used to "simulate" mod_rewrite-style URL rewriting.

Using pathinfo, you can do the following:

```
http://testserver/index.php/path/to/foo/bar/1/2/3/
```

This will invoke `index.php` and serve the remaining URL fragment as `PATH_INFO`. This is used, as I said, to set up a central front controller with "beautiful" URLs without mod_rewrite.

Now in your case, the same thing happens, only that

```
http://testserver/path/to/foo
```

gets translated - either through `mod_speling`, the negotiation module or a third module whose name I forgot - into

```
http://testserver/path/to/foo.php
```

The rest of the path gets faithfully passed to that file.

So it's intended behaviour, albeit weird and unexpected.

Comment: Good info, but having `/index.php` prefix every path is *not* beautiful.