# RewriteRule not work with " / "

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I test UrlRewrite in local with wamp and i search to do this :

index.php?test=test123 **to** index/test123 with query string

My .htaccess :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Rule
RewriteRule ^index/([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?test=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it's work but $_GET["test"] is empty.. If i test this :

```
RewriteRule ^index-([a-z0-9]+)$ index.php?test=$1 [QSA,L]
```

It's work. $_GET["test"] = "test123".

When separate " - " work and " / " not work ?

Comment: Tested. Your rule with `/` works as expected.

Comment: Disable content negociation with: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultviViews`

Comment: i tested in my server and work too, but why not locally ?

Comment: @julp thanks, it's work fine with `-MultiViews`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache/PHP is determined to serve the wrong file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620635/apache-php-is-determined-to-serve-the-wrong-file)